# apply grayscale to view and its children

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-color

It is rather simple to change the alpha of a view and it's children: You change the alpha of the view and incidentally the alpha will be applied to all of its children.

I want to do the same thing except with graying out a view (it could be blueing out or whatever). The point is: how do I grayscale a view programmatically/dynamically?  It that is too hard, how about applying a scrim/foreground on the view?

Comment: have you try setting the tint attribute to a transparent gray?

Comment: what do you mean? `view.setForegroundTintList(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

Set a transparent gray tint using this method using DrawableCompat and see if it's working for you... :

```
public static Drawable setTint(Drawable drawable, int color) {
    final Drawable newDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
    DrawableCompat.setTint(newDrawable, color);
    return newDrawable;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. But I am not sure what I am supposed to do with your method. Where am I to get the parameters from? `(Drawable drawable, int color)` and then where do I set it on the view? with  `setForeground`?